# How to construct a function with these hypotheses?

Tags: functions, generating-functions, functional-equations, rational-functions

I want to construct a function $f:[0,1]×[0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]$ such that

- $f(0,t)=t$
- $f(1,t)=2t-1$ $ \forall$ $ t\geq \frac{1}{2}$
- $f(s,t)=0$ $ \forall $ $0 \leq t \leq \frac{s}{2}$
- $f(s,\frac{s}{2})=0$
- $f(s,1)=1$
- $f$ is continuous

I have the function but not sure how it has been constructed rigorously and the procedure for constructing the same

This is the function
$f(s,t)=\frac{2t-s}{2-s}$

**PS:** Also, is such a function unique. If so, how can it be proved ?

Comment: These properties do *not* uniquely define $f$. They only define the values of $f$ on four line segments in the unit square. Outside these segments, any choice of $f(x,y)\in[0,1]$ will yield a solution.

Comment: Yes. I need one more condition. I will add that. Thank you

Comment: Your change didn't fix much. You still have nothing that requires $f$ to haven any definite form on the interior of the square above the line $t = s/2$. There are uncountably many continuous functions that will work. Even requiring infinite differentiability still allows an infinite number of solutions (not including yours, since the form you gave can only hold for $t\ge s/2$.)

Comment: @PaulSinclair Okay. But how is that function constructed procedurally ?

Comment: If there were some means of constructing your function from the information given, then there would be only one function that satisfied that information. But Servaes and I have told you that there are INFINITELY MANY functions that satisfy your conditions. We have even told you why your conditions are insufficient to construct anything. Please give up demanding that somehow despite all this, that you can still construct your function from it.

Comment: @PaulSinclair You have answered the second part of question i.e. there are infinitely many such functions lest I am not sure of it for I have to find some proof. I didn't get why you say that conditions are insufficient to construct function contrary to fact that imposing less suitable conditions gives more number of functions. Besides,I agree that there may not be unique way of constructing a function. I just wanted to know how is that function ($f(s,t)=\frac{2t-s}{t-s}$) constructed with those conditions which is satisfied by the latter.

Comment: Here's why you probably can't find a construction leading to the function you've mentioned: If the only thing that you know about the function you seek is the conditions given, the construction you're trying to give should result in any solution of those conditions. This only happens when all the solutions are somehow of the same form, and for example you use a parameter, the value of which identifies a single function. This is what happens when you describe the family of solutions of the differential equation $ x '' = x $ as $ a e ^ x + b e ^ { - x } $. Each pair $( a , b )$ gives a solution.

Comment: In the case of your problem, this doesn't happen. The solutions don't share a similar form, so you can't do that. The thing you can do, is adding some other conditions and searching the solutions which also have the new condition. For example, you can assume that $ f ( s , t ) $ is of the form $ \frac { a s + b t + c } { d s + e t + u } $ and try to find out which values of the parameters give a solution. But there is no way that you know from the first step that which additional conditions are suitable for a given problem, and which are not.

Comment: @MohsenShahriari You are claiming that there will be an explicit general form for every continuous function as a solution to certain hyptheses, atleast in case of my problem. And assuming if this is true, you are saying that the function I have mentioned doesn't satisfy any general form.   Isn't this too much to assume

Comment: I'm not claiming there is a general form, I'm saying that you can try to find the solutions that have some guessed form, which may not be all the solutions. The assumption that the solution is of that form is the "additional condition" that I mentioned. I didn't claim that every solution satisfies this additional condition. I just said that you can check wether there is any solution with that condition, or not.

Comment: The family of all the solutions of your problem doesn't come from a general form. So the question is: is there a better way to describe that family, other than being the functions satisfying the given conditions? Probably not. That's the other thing I said.